# Avoid 'uploads' 777 permissions: Potential threat or clean solution?

Tags: security, directory, permissions, filesystem, command-line

Recently changed hosting of a website and found the upload directory of WordPress wasn't "available". I have been reading that setting folder permissions to 777 would allow everything to work fine, but I consider this a big security issue, and a future problem for sure.

SCENARIO:

The folder's (and its contents) permissions are 755, an administrative account was the owner/group of it and WordPress wasn't working properly in the Media dashboard within the web CMS.

So, I have came up with a solution, in fact the matter of my question:

SOLUTION(?)

- Searched the user that executes the web server (NginX, Apache,
  Cherokee, etc...):

  ps -aux
- Assign that user as owner/group of wp_content/uploads recursively:

  chmod -R username uploads/ chgrp -R username uploads/
- Found a GeoIP.dat and GeoIPV6.dat files within uploads/ folder, then assign the former owner/group to those executable files.
- Since that, I have been able to upload my files again through the
  media dashboard in the WordPress CMS without any trouble.

Is this practice safer than the 777 permissions? I mean, maybe it could be reachable through the web, sure, but since there are a couple security plugins running already, I have little concern about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**:

YES, is a big time threat.

**Explained**:

Little time has passed since I asked this question but now I have found that the safer and most useful file permissions for wordpress are the following:

**Directories: 755** `Owner can: Read, write and execute. Group and public can: Read and execute.`

**Read-only files:644** `Owner can: Read and write. Group and public can read only.`

Example of read only files:

- *.css
- *.htm
- *.html
- *.jpeg
- *.jpg
- *.gif
- *.png
- *.js
- *.mpeg
- *.mpg
- *.mp3
- *.avi
- *.txt
- *.doc
- *.pdf

**Executable files:700** `Owner can: Read, write and execute.`

Example of executable files:

- *.php
- *.cgi
- *.pl
- *.py
- *.rb

**TO IMPLEMENT THE CHANGES (in terminal)**:

Determine where are you, this will tell you that.

```
pwd
```

Once you get to the desired folder (there were the wp-config.php lays) in order to change the directory permissions you could try:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Where: **-type d** stands for instances listed as directories found by `find` command.

Then:

```
sudo find . -type f \( -iname '*.css' \-or -iname '*.htm*' \-or -iname '*.jpeg' \-or -iname '*.jpg' \-or -iname '*.gif' \-or -iname '*.png' \-or -iname '*.js' \-or -iname '*.mpeg' \-or -iname '*.mpg' \-or -iname '*.mp3' \-or -iname '*.avi' \-or -iname '*.txt' \-or -iname '*.doc' \-or -iname '*.pdf' \) -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Where: **-type f** stands for instances listed as files with given file extensions founded by `find` command.

And finally:

```
find . -type f \( -iname '*.php*' \-or -iname '*.cgi' \-or -iname '*.pl' \-or -iname '*.py' \-or -iname '*.rb' \) -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

Where: (again) **-type f** stands for instances listed as files with given file extensions founded by `find` command.

Happy server management.